# Remove duplicate module from browserify bundle

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have a browserify bundle, let's call it `core.js`, that contains a `require('../module-a');` statement.  `core.js` is included on every page on my website.

I have a separate bundle that is page-specific, let's call it `page.js`.  Inside `page.js`, there is a `require('../../some/folder/module-a');` statement.

As of right now, `module-a` is duplicated in both `core.js` and `page.js`.  What I would like is to tell browserify that when `page.js` is generated, search the `core.js` bundle for `module-a` first, and use `module-a` from that bundle if it exists.

What I don't want is to generate a `common.js` bundle that includes shared code from both `core.js` and `page.js`.  I want `core.js` to stay the same, and to simply trim down `page.js`.  I also don't want to have to manually tell the `page.js` bundle that `core.js` already contains `module-a`, I have way too many modules for that to be feasible.  I need it to be done programmatically.

Is this possible?

Comment: hi! I've tried to reproduce your case. Take a look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/R1ZZU/df348748a3bab6c71437). Seems like browserify resolved duplicated modules without any configuration. Can you please provide more info?

Comment: In your gist it looks like you only generated one bundle.  The scenario I described above involves two separate bundles that both reference a common module.

Answer (score 1):

You, actually, can't do this by browserify configuration, because browserify doesn't know about bundles it created before and can't join modules from two separately compiled bundles.

Probably, the simplest solution is let your `page.js` module to know if `core.js` is included before you compile `page.js`. It depends on which tool do you use along with `browserify` to compile bundles.

So, as I said, you can't do what you want without writing some logic around the bundles.